# How to manage multiple database connections?

Tags: postgresql, python-3.x

I want a nice and clean way for accessing my Postgres databases in python.

Currently, I have a file called `database.py` which has some imports within it.

The imports look like this:

```
from DatabaseA import dbA
from DatabaseB import dbB
```

`DatabaseA` and `DatabaseB` each have their own methods for performing various queries against their respective database connection.

I would now, in my file where I need to use a database, add the import `import database` and then do something like:

```
database.DbA.create_table(table_name)
database.DbB.do_something(some_args)
```

My database scripts (eg `DatabaseA`) each get their connection details from a config.ini file.

This all works, but I'd like to have it more object orientated.

It would be nice to be able to specify a master DB "manager", and then access the respective DB by passing in a configuration name (so that it can get the required connection details and return the correct database file). For example:

```
DBManager().get_db("DbA_config_name").create_table("test_table")
```

Where "DbA_config_name" is the name of the configuration in the config.ini file (accessed using configparser).

What patterns exist for this type of thing in Python?